# Не работает nodejs скрипт, запущенный через exec в php

Tags: php, node.js

Почему-то не работает NodeJS скрипт, вызванный из php посредством exec. Вызываю скрипт таким образом:

```
exec('cd /var/www/developer/flaut/dev; node doSingleSnapshot.js ' . urlencode('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Содержание скрипта **doSingleSnapshot.js**:

```
var path = require("path");
var util = require("util");
var htmlSnapshots = require("html-snapshots");

let uri = decodeURIComponent(process.argv[2]);

htmlSnapshots.run({
    input: "array",
    source: [uri],
    outputDir: '/var/www/production/flaut/snapshots/',
    pollInterval: 3000,
    timeout: 250000,
    phantomjsOptions: [
        "--ssl-protocol=any",
        "--ignore-ssl-errors=true"
    ]

});
```

Когда пытаюсь открыть php-скрипт, запускающий `exec()`, то он просто висит и через 25 секунд выдаёт ошибку **504 Gateway Timed-Out**; Если запускать Node-скрипт руками из консоли - он работает, без ошибок. Думал, что проблема в правах и сделал `chown -R www-data:www-data doSingleSnapshot.js`, но это ничего не изменило. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

В PHP можно выполнять shell команды с помощью `system()`. Попробуйте вызвать скрипт из `system()` как из обычного терминала. Подробнее прочитайте про функцию. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.system.php

Comment: `system()` вроде работает, выполнение файла запускает, но почему-то запущенный с его помощью скрипт не может открывать файлы. `PhantomJS error: Unable to open file`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась. Прописал команду `chown -R www-data:www-data` на папку, где лежал все файлы снапшотов.